# Trivial norm is equivalent only to itself

Tags: normed-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, equivalent-metrics

> Trivial norm is equivalent only to itself (on a field)

The norm here fulfills $3$ requirements

$(1) |x|\ge0$ and $ |x|=0\iff x=0$

$(2)|x\cdot y|=|x|\cdot|y|$

$(3)|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$

$2$ norms are said to be equivalent iff they induce equivalent metrics, and $2$ metrics $d_1,d_2$ are said to be equivalent if a sequence is Cauchy w.r. to $d_1$ iff it is Cauchy w.r. to $d_2$

So when I pick the trivial norm, i.e. $ |x| = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $x \neq 0$};\\
        0 & \mbox{if $x = 0$}.\end{array} \right. $

and any nontrivial norm $|.|'$ then choose any nonzero element $x$ with $|x|'\neq1$ such an element must exist so if $|x|'>1$ then take $x^{-1}=:y$ so $|y|'<1$ and the sequence $\{y^n\}_n$ is Cauchy w.r. to $|.|'$ because for $n\ge m\ge N:|y^n-y^m|\le|y^n|+|y^m|\le2|y^m|\le2|y^N|$ and not Cauchy in $|.|$ because $\nexists N;n,m\ge N\implies|y^n-y^m|<1$

Is this enough ? I cannot mention any topology or balls, I have to stick to the definition

Comment: Why is $\{y^n\}_n$ Cauchy with respect to $|\cdot |'$?

Comment: @kccu Is it not ? say $m\le n$ then $|y^m-y^n|'\le|y^m|'+|y^n|'\le|y^m|'\cdot2$

Comment: Your "trivial norm" is not a norm, since $|2x| ≠ 2|x|$

Comment: @CalvinKhor What needs to be fixed ?

Comment: Don't call it a norm? Its pretty much the discrete metric. See absolute homogeneity in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: @CalvinKhor it is taken from the book https://ibb.co/jk295zC

Comment: I suppose they replace $\|kx\| = |k|\|x\|$ with $N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$. I don't think the real-analysis tag is correct, you should probably tag with a $p$-adics related tag and add this context to the question

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes the book is about p-adics, but the question not so

Comment: Well my sense is that you're going to confuse people who (like me) use the definition of a norm on a $\mathbb K$-vector space instead of the definition for a norm on some ..ring? I don't know. Up to you.

Comment: @counterfeit I agree with that inequality, but my question is why $|y^m|'$ should go to zero as $m$ goes to infinity. You haven't said anything about how your norm plays with multiplication in the field.

Answer (score 1):

I think your argument is essentially correct. You can add to clarify that in the trivial norm, $\lvert z \rvert < 1 \Leftrightarrow z = 0$ and a sequence is Cauchy if and only if it is eventually constant. Also, the last line should read
$\not \exists N: \color{red}{\forall} m,n \ge N: \lvert y^m-y^n\rvert < 1$
which you still have to show -- I would write $y^m - y^n = y^m (y^{m-n}-1)$, the first factor cannot be $0$ because $y \neq 0$ and we're in a field, the second factor cannot be zero for $m \neq n$ because $\lvert y^{m-n} \rvert = \lvert y \rvert^{m-n} \neq 1 = \lvert 1 \rvert$ by choice of $y$.

Besides those (maybe pedantic) mathematical points, I think your argument would also be improved by correct sentences, grammar, and punctuation. That is no small issue. As it stands, your decisive paragraph is a run-on sentence going "So when ... then ... and ... because ... and not ... because ... ." Please break that up into smaller bits.